# Ansible sysctl tries to reload ipv6, even though ipv6 is disabled

Tags: security, ansible, ipv6, rhel8

Consider this:

I have a RHEL8 server where ipv6 is disabled.
I'm running some ansible scripts for security compliance.

Ansible check looks like this :

```
- name: "SCORED | 3.1.1 | PATCH | Ensure IP forwarding is disabled"
  block:
  - name: "SCORED | 3.1.1 | PATCH | Ensure IP forwarding is disabled | Disable IPv4 forwarding"
    sysctl:
        name: '{{ item.name }}'
        value: '{{ item.value }}'
        state: present
        reload: yes
        ignoreerrors: yes
    with_items:
        - { name: net.ipv4.ip_forward, value: 0 }
        - { name: net.ipv4.route.flush, value: 1}

    notify:
        - sysctl flush ipv4 route table

  - name: "SCORED | 3.1.1 | PATCH | Ensure IP forwarding is disabled | Disable IPv6 forwarding"
    sysctl:
        name: '{{ item.name }}'
        value: '{{ item.value }}'
        state: present
        reload: yes
        ignoreerrors: yes
    with_items:
        - { name: net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding, value: 0 }
        - { name: net.ipv6.route.flush, value: 1}
    when:
        - rhel8cis_ipv6_required
    notify:
        - sysctl flush ipv6 route table
  when:
    - not rhel8cis_is_router
    - rhel8cis_rule_3_1_1
  tags:
    - level1
    - sysctl
    - patch
    - rule_3.1.1
```

Variable

> rhel8cis_ipv6_required
> is set to false.

The handlers that are being called look like this:

```
- name: sysctl flush ipv4 route table
  become: yes
  sysctl:
    name: net.ipv4.route.flush
    value: 1
    sysctl_set: yes
  when: ansible_virtualization_type != "docker"

- name: sysctl flush ipv6 route table
  become: yes
  sysctl:
    name: net.ipv6.route.flush
    value: 1
    sysctl_set: yes
  when: ansible_virtualization_type != "docker"
```

The output of the playbook looks like this:

> TASK [RHEL8_CIS : SCORED | 3.1.1 | PATCH | Ensure IP forwarding is disabled | Disable IPv4 forwarding]  **************************************************************************************************************************************
> ok: [alrha001.acc.vlkintern.nl] => (item={'name': 'net.ipv4.ip_forward', 'value': 0})
> changed: [alrha001.acc.vlkintern.nl] => (item={'name': 'net.ipv4.route.flush', 'value': 1})

> TASK [RHEL8_CIS : SCORED | 3.1.1 | PATCH | Ensure IP forwarding is disabled | Disable IPv6   forwarding] **************************************************************************************************************************************
> skipping: [alrha001.acc.vlkintern.nl] => (item={'name': 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding',   'value': 0})
> skipping: [alrha001.acc.vlkintern.nl] => (item={'name': 'net.ipv6.route.flush', 'value': 1})

> RUNNING HANDLER [RHEL8_CIS : sysctl flush ipv4 route table] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
> [WARNING]: The value 1 (type int) in a string field was converted to '1' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.

> fatal: [alrha001.acc.vlkintern.nl]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to reload sysctl: fs.suid_dumpable = 0\nkernel.randomize_va_space = 2\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 0\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 1\nnet.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1\nnet.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1\nnet.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1\nnet.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1\nnet.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1\nnet.ipv4.route.flush = 1\nnet.ipv4.ip_forward = 0\nsysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/flush: No such file or directory\nsysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding: No such file or directory\n"}

And this is where I'm completely confused.
As you can see, the handler for ipv4 is executed. All variables shown in the fatal output pertain to ipv4. Yet, at the end, the handler complains that it cannot find ipv6 files. Which is correct, because on this server ipv6 is not enabled.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Put the ipv6 route flush in quotes as advised and so ... name: net.ipv6.route.flush, value: "1"

Comment: Did that, but that was not the solution. Same behavior.....

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you have an ipv6 key in your `/etc/sysctl.conf`, maybe from before this remediation, or caused by it earlier. That will normally be ignored, but it happens to cause a failure here due to a combination of factors.

The ansible `sysctl` module always tries to update a sysctl file on disk, by default `/etc/sysctl.conf`. It has no provision for a temporary change. Here the handler is trying to make a point-in-time change (route flush), but it will incorrectly make a permanent change by writing this update to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. The permanent change causes the file to be reloaded (because `reload:` defaults to `yes`) and the `sysctl` module then fails because it is very strict about every key working. So it's detecting your unrelated ipv6 key and failing.

In short, this is a handler bug. Change the handler to use the `sysctl` command directly and it should work.

```
- name: sysctl flush ipv4 route
  command: sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1
  ...
```

It's also possible to use `ignoreerrors: yes` with the `sysctl` module so that the handler doesn't crash, or even `reload: no`. But that still makes the change permanent, so the proper solution is to manually issue the sysctl. In fact, Red Hat [explicitly says](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/915363) you can't use this flush key in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. (Link behind their paywall, unfortunately.)

For the same reason, you might need to set `ignoreerrors: yes` if you ever write a playbook that actually needs to modify `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and if you could have an invalid key in there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are asking the IPv6 settings to be modified; however, beacuse you do not have IPv6 enabled those settings do not exist. Take a look at the IPv6 flush statement:

```
- name: sysctl flush ipv6 route table
  become: yes
  sysctl:
    name: net.ipv6.route.flush
    value: 1
    sysctl_set: yes
  when: ansible_virtualization_type != "docker"
```

Under the hood, `sysctl` performs this action by using the special file `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/flush` in procfs. This file, as well as everything in `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/`, does not exist unless IPv6 is enabled. I think your other IPv6 statements are failing for the same reason, they are trying to access parameters in `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/` that do not exist.

Comment: Are u sure ?
I see that the handler for ipv4 is executed, not the handler for ipv6....
What I was trying to say is that the ipv4 handler tries to do something with ipv6 settings as well....

Comment: In the output above the only time IPv4 and IPv6 are in the same snippet is the last one which flushes tables. The statement you showed for that IPv6 flush tables, does not have a `when` condition to not run if IPv6. If the prior IPv6 task ran as you expected add `when` with `- rhel8cis_ipv6_required`, to the IPv6 flush statement